# Using find_element_by_xpath inside span

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to automatically navigate web pages using python, selenium, xpath.
I want to click a next page button in a page whose code is like this:

```
<a _ngcontent-pnd-c43="" automation-id="discover-market-next-button"
class="menu-item-button ng-star-inserted">
<span _ngcontent-pnd-c43="" class="nav-button-right sprite"></span>
</a>
```

I tried with the following code:

```
try:
    element='//span[class="nav-button-right sprite"]'
    button_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button_next).click(button_next).perform()
    time.sleep(15)
    content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print ("NoSuchElementException")
```

but I got "NoSuchElementException".
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `nav-button-right sprite` is not a class, not even an attribute name. So try changing you xpath expression from:

```
element='//span[class="nav-button-right sprite"]'
```

to:

```
element='//span[@_ngcontent-pnd-c43]'
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I simply missed @ before class...

Answer (score 0):

You less `@` in:

```
element='//span[@class="nav-button-right sprite"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your XPath, you missed `@` symbol after class, try this hope it helps:

```
element='//span[@class='nav-button-right sprite']'
```